# How to place an integer you just inputted on the dialog box TITLE bar

Tags: java, dialog, joptionpane, titlebar, box

Hello people of Stackoverflow, I'm trying to make a Java program that has a title bar with the inputted integer. So here's a little of my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConvertHoursToMinutes {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int hours;
    int minutes;


    hours=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter hour: "));

    minutes=hours*60;

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Converted into minutes is: " +minutes,"is equivalent to",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


}
```

}

What I want to happen is that, ON THE TITLE BAR OF THE DIALOG BOX, it is default on the output that what's written is MESSAGE right? So I wanted to make it, " *the number inputted by the user* is equivalent to" what I have on my title bar is only "in minutes is..." please help thanks. I tried searching on Google but I can't find answers.

For example, the user entered 1.

So my title bar (i am hoping) that it should be...

1 in minutes is...

then the output goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the variable to the String in the message box. Change your message dialog to the following:

```
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Converted into minutes is: " + minutes, hours + " is equivalent to", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

According to the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) you are using, this will set the

```
message: "Converted into minutes is 60" //for example
title: "is equivelant to: 1" //for example
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it has an error int "cannot be converted to Icon"

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want your message box to say? What is the exact message, and what is the exact title you would like?

Comment: &Kon "(the number inputted by the user) is equivalent to" ex "1 is equivalent to"

Comment: Something like this https://z-n.ak.fbcdn.net/sphotos-h.ak/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10462962_10202414884042049_3004835478653678598_n.jpg?oh=de7399376dda0bcb1b1f83f578e97335&oe=53AA34FE&__gda__=1403695825_2a65c71697b8f14df43a719fe97c4e3b

Comment: @user3767918 I have editted my reply above. Please try copying the line of code exactly as-is and seeing if the output is what you expect. I can then explain what is going on here exactly.

Comment: Im sorry i did not notice that you already edited it. Thanks! Now I know my error, instead of having hour+, i keep on doing +hour. (sorry still not really good at java) Thank you!

Comment: No problem, as long as you understand what went wrong.